# Why does B work as a bass note against F7 in Bb?

Tags: theory, chords

I wrote a song in Band-in-a-Box.  It includes this turnaround:

Dm Dbm Cm F7/B BbMaj7

The chord F7/B doesn't sound good on guitar (I play it as F7 or F9 instead), but the low B note works really well on bass.  What's going on here, theory-wise?

Answer (score 16):

It's known as a tritone substitution. In jazz you can substitute any dominant-seventh chord with the one a tritone (b5 or #4) away. This works because of the major-third and minor-seventh which are in every dominant-seventh chord. These make the interval of a tritone, which is exactly half an octave, and so gives exactly the same notes when transposed by a tritone. Another way to think about it is this: an incomplete (no 5th, but still fully functioning) F7 chord could have the notes F, A and Eb, which are root, maj3 and min7. If you transpose the root by a tritone you get B, A and Eb, which is enharmonically a B7 chord without a 5th (although the Eb would be "spelled" as a D#). Crucially, only the root has been transposed by a tritone; the other two notes remain the same, but their function has changed. The A is now the min7 and the D# is the maj3.

When doing this kind of tritone substitution, you can either transpose the whole dominant-seventh chord, e.g. F7 becomes B7, or place the dominant-seventh chord over a bass note a tritone away, as happens above with the use of a "slash chord". This latter usage gives a more interesting, extended, jazzy chord, once one takes into account the two notes which are *not* common to both an F7 and B7, in other words the F and C from the F7 chord. Over a B bass these function as a #11 (or b5) and a b9. This type of tritone substitution is particularly strong at a V7-I cadence; where the bass would usually move up a fourth (or down a fifth), in this case F-Bb, the bass now moves by a semitone, B-Bb, which is a particularly strong movement. The effect of this chromatic movement in your example is heightened further by being the culmination of a string of semitones leading down to the Bb.

Comment: +1 again! Going back to I from V7 the nice choice is one semitone below or one semitone above on bass. I do it all the time! The semitone drops also let the listener expect that tts in this case.

Comment: The theory geek in me really wants to call this Cb7.  But great answer!

Comment: Which has a B-double-flat of course...!

Answer (score 3):

the third (A) and seventh (Eb) of F7 also correspond to the third (Eb) and seventh (A) of B7, so you are basically substituting B7 for F7 (with some of the tension notes altered on the B7: #4 and b9 which are typical modifications on a dominant 7th).

Comment: Third of B is called D# rather than Eb. Flat 5ths are far more likely than #4ths.

Comment: yeah but more confusing for the OP, but you make a good point

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to come at this from a slightly different angle. The kind of of chord you're using is from a class of chords that has been in use for 400-500 years, specifically augmented sixth chords, and you are using it in fairly standard fashion. (Yes, I would spell the bass note as C♭.) Here's the [Wikipedia article on augmented sixths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sixth_chord).

The class of chord arose from voice leading considerations when adapting the Phrygian final cadence (♭vii<sup>6</sup>-I) for use as a predominant in a half-cadence in the minor mode (iv<sup>6</sup>-V). Eventually a formula arose where a chromatic passing tone was interpolated between the root of the sixth chord and the root of the following chord, and, as these things are wont to happen, the root of the sixth chord fell away, leaving the augmented sixth in its place. What was left was a kind of artificial chord that partook of the plagal/subdominant voice leading characteristics of the original Phrygian cadence *and* the dominant voice leading characteristics of a V of V-V half-cadence (or V-I authentic cadence), with both upper and lower leading tones. Eventually other notes were added to stress the dominant-style voice leading. The following more or less illustrates the progression, using B♭ major as the target chord. Note that C♭ is *diatonic* in both B♭ Phrygian and E♭ minor.

[image: Example of augmented sixths]

Example A is the standard Phrygian cadence. As a final cadence, the D♮ would usually be ornamented with a C♮ mordent (assuming that they would have used that many flats in the days of modal polyphony). Example B shows the interpolation of the augmented 6th as a passing note in a half-cadence; Example C uses the free-standing augmented sixth (an Italian 6th chord); and Example D adds an F to form a gapped F dominant 7th chord over the bass (a French 6th chord).

The last example should look familiar: add C♮ to fill out the F7, and it's your chord. The difference from conventional classical usage is that you're using it in a transitional passage after parallel movement by the semitone (but that parallel movement has brought the music into an increasingly flat tonality), and you're suspending the A♮. You're also treating B♭ as the tonic, so you could say that you're bringing the cadential formula back to the Phrygian mode...

...and that's probably the best way to describe what's happening here: it is *not* a tritone substitution; it's a *modal* substitution involving a voice leading-based formula *whose bass is diatonic in the formula's native mode(s)*. I think that modal substitution and appropriation of modal formulae are more common causes of chromaticism than most people realise: in fact, the augmented sixth chords themselves came about by substituting melodic cadential formulae from the major into a minor mode cadence.

The French sixth *without* C♮ is a symmetrical whole-tone chord that can be subjected to tritone substitution (or rearrangement, perhaps), but the substitution would involve *F* in the bass, with a *gapped B7* superimposed, and that's not what's happening in your music. The primary tones of your chord, and the progression in which it is used, have been around since long before Liszt, Rimsky-Korsakoff, Scriabin, etc. started experimenting with tritone substitution. That is why it sounds so acceptable - it's been part of the scenery for a long time.